# How to get methods properties values - PHP

Tags: php, class, object

I have this code and wonder get the methods properties values.

```
<?php
class framework{
        
        // users table
        function users(){
            $username="VARCHAR (255)";
            $email="VARCHAR (255)";
            $password="VARCHAR (255)";
        }

        // product table
        function produts(){
            $title="VARCHAR (255)";
            $price="INT ()";
            $author="VARCHAR (255)";

        }

        //categories table
        function categories(){
            $category_name="VARCHAR (255)";
        }

        
    }

?>
```

> I'm trying to create my own framework and in this particular code I'm trying to simplify database creation. The idea is to get the class name as the database name and the methods as tables names, and the last get the methods properties as cols.

I use get_class() to get the class name and add as table name;
get_class_methods to get the class methods and create the table.

So I have no idea of how to create the respective cols.

Comment: What's your question about this code?

Comment: There's no such thing as *method properties*, you are just creating variables in the methods.

Comment: Also, using `var` and no visibility seems like a bad idea in 2022 for a new framework.

Comment: I'll change **var** to **public**.

Comment: I want to get the object vars

Comment: Do you want to get class or function names dynamically ? Is this what you looking for

Comment: You should probably have a look at database migrations instead of this approach. Have a look at https://phinx.org/ perhaps you can extend that.

Comment: Hmm, this seems way too low-level and complex to be inside a generic "Framework" class. You are describing database definitions (DDL) here and this, even on a small project, would make the Framework class large and complicated. Perhaps take a step back and think about breaking it up a bit more. For example, MVC frameworks use "models" to work with the underlying tables and each model usually relates to a single table. You _can_ work with the DDL directly in a model (ex. Django), but many frameworks choose to do this in separate migration files (ex. Laravel).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not recommending this approach because you are reinventing the wheel here, but you could expose your DDL info via public properties. Of course, you can make these `private`/`protected` and expose them via getters.

I also created a base model which your child models can inherit. This allows for IDE autocompletion in the `DatabaseBuilder` below.

```
<?php

namespace Bartolomeu;

// Base model
abstract class Model {
    public $table;
    public $columns;
}

class User extends Model
{
    public $table = 'users';

    public $columns = [
        'username' => 'VARCHAR (255)',
        'email' => 'VARCHAR (255)',
        'password' => 'VARCHAR (255)',
    ];
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public $table = 'products';

    public $columns = [
        'title' => 'VARCHAR (255)',
        'price' => 'INT ()',
        'author' => 'VARCHAR (255)',
    ];
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public $table = 'categories';

    public $columns = [
        'category_name' => 'VARCHAR (255)',
    ];
}
```

Finally, you can create a class that will actually "read" the models and do the necessary work to create the tables themselves.

```
<?php

class DatabaseBuilder
{
    public function createTables()
    {
        $models = [
            new User(),
            new Product(),
            new Category(),
        ];

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            /* @var Model $model */

            $table = $model->table;
            $columns = $model->columns;

            //...
        }
    }
}
```